# Dialogflow Encoding Problems when switching to API v2

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow for my Action on Google. The fulfillment webhook is hosted on AWS Lambda and implemented using the [Actions on Google NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) version `2.0.1`.

Everything works fine when I select the legacy API version `V1 API` in the general settings of my Dialogflow agent.

Switching to `V2 API` causes encoding problems. This affects the umlauts in the German version of my Action (e.g. `ä` is converted to `Ã¤`).

Looking at the *Diagnostic info* of a test request made in the Dialogflow console I can see that the *Fulfillment Response* is still encoded correctly, but the *Raw API Response* contains the strangely encoded characters.

Any idea what's going on here?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading the Actions on Google NodeJS SDK from version `2.0.1` to `2.1.1` solved the problem.

In version `2.0.1` the `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8` header was missing from the response. Since the ability to send back headers was added in [this commit](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/commit/7efa4857dca177b587929d6f0327e11b63105e4d) the issue is gone.